Secure window ac installation advice wanted (no drilling)
Secure window AC no damage to window frame
I saw this YouTube video showing how to securely install a window AC without drilling into the frame. I want to do a similar thing because I recently got a new AC unit and I don’t want to have 3 new holes in the frame. The only problem is my window sash has a lip hanging over the top frame of the ac. I was wondering if I could get tips of how to replicate the same solution.
This is the video in question: https://youtu.be/B13UA4Zeyvg?si=-YVO4zY8_CQAdPPm
This is my window sash: https://i.ibb.co/BjLGm33/IMG-2766.jpg
Here’s what I was thinking to use instead of an l-shaped brace .

What's the piece in your pic with the dot/hole right in the middle?
